# More elegant solution to using Python string in a SQL query

Tags: python, sql

I'm using Python to query a database. I have a pandas DataFrame containing unique date values, as such (this is a sample, there are many more rows):

```
df_dt
          DATE
0   2023-01-14
1   2023-01-16
2   2023-01-12
```

I need to query another table using the dates above. That is, I need to query a table SOME_TABLE using the dates from the dataframe above, using an IN clause (maybe something else?). I found a solution, but I was wondering if there is a better one. The one I found iterates through the dataframe rows and appends the dates to a string:

```
str_dates = ""
for index, date in enumerate(df_dt.iterrows()):
    if index == df_dt.shape[0] - 1:
        str_dates = str_dates + \
            f"TO_DATE('{date[1].iloc[0].date()}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"
    else:
        str_dates = str_dates + \
            f"TO_DATE('{date[1].iloc[0].date()}', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),\n\t\t"
```

The if takes care of the last date, which cannot have a comma after `'YYYY-MM-DD')` (or else the query breaks). This string is then inserted into another one:

```
query = \
f"""
SELECT 
    SOME_VARIABLE
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE DATE IN (
    {dates}
)
"""
```

Using the sample above, the result is:

```
print(query)
    SELECT 
        SOME_VARIABLE
    FROM SOME_TABLE
    WHERE DATE IN (
        TO_DATE('2023-01-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
        TO_DATE('2023-01-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
        TO_DATE('2023-01-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    )
```

This works but I would like a more elegant solution

Comment: What are you looking for in terms of elegance?

Comment: I was looking for something more succinct, preferably without an if-else clause. Your answer is great, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `join()`

```
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng}) 

str_dates = [f"TO_DATE('{dt.date()}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')" for dt in df['Date']]
sql_dates = ",\n".join(str_dates)

print(sql_dates)
```

You'll get:

```
TO_DATE('2015-02-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
TO_DATE('2015-02-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
TO_DATE('2015-02-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
TO_DATE('2015-02-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
TO_DATE('2015-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```